# How to get a ProgressBar (or a button...) into class in android through koltin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-button, android-progressbar

I need to know how to call a ProgressBar (or any other kind of button) into a class, outside of "onCreate" method.
I saw in Java I can do it calling findViewById(), however it's been rid of in Kotlin.
For example I was trying a thing like this:

```
 var myProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar) as ProgressBar
```

But it gives me the unresolved reference for the find view method.

Thanks in advance for help

______________UPDATE____________________

Here's my DownloadManager custom class

```
class DownloadSoundController(context: Context): Activity() {

val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
.....
.....
      Thread(Runnable{
        while (starter) {
            var query = DownloadManager.Query()
            query.setFilterById(refid)
            var c = downloadManager.query(query)

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                var totalSizeIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES)
                var downloadedIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR)
                val fileSize = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES))
                var totalSize = c.getInt(totalSizeIndex)
                var downloaded = c.getInt(downloadedIndex)
                var progress = 0.0
                var raffronto: Long = -1

                if (fileSize != raffronto) {
                    progress = downloaded * 100.0 / totalSize
                    //println("myTag - downloaded % :$progress, downloaded var: $downloaded")
                    myProgressBar.progress = progress.toInt()
                    if (progress == 100.0) {
                        starter = false
                    }
                } else {
                    //println("myTag - downloaded = 100 progress: $progress, $downloaded")
                    myProgressBar.progress = progress.toInt()
                    if (progress == 100.0) {
                        starter = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start()
```

Here's my manifest:

```
<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            tools:replace="screenOrientation" />

    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
//ATTENTION
   <activity android:name="com.example.myapplication.DownloadSoundController"/> 
// here it returns ERROR, on default constructor

    <receiver android:name=".DownloadBroadcastManager">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

_________UPDATE_2__________

I polished the code and I found several issues that sound really "weird" to me:

1) to stop the nullpoint exception about myProgressBar.progress = value, I found out I have to initialize myProgressBar.progress = 0

2) With println() my thread stamps into the log exactly, step by step, the downloaded amount of my file, but if I add the myProgressBar.progress = progress.toInt() (progress var is THE SAME I stamp into the println()!) in the Thread... it starts to be async in a way it EVEN STARTS BEFORE the download has begun.. leading to several errors and **multiple** downloads"

I really don't know what's going on

Comment: I don't think Kotlin doesn't have access to findViewById. Maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I updated again... it's really "weird"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` now returns a generic type which extends `View` ([docs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)).

```
final <T extends View> T findViewById(...)
```

You can use

```
val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.myProgressBar)
```

Comment: It seems it keeps to gimme a mark as "unresolved". I tried and I can call the progressBar in every function in main activity, however I need it in another class.kt file

Comment: @MicheleRava are you sure you're using the correct SDK version?

Comment: I added the :Activity() constructor. Now it can see the myProgressBar, as it happens in MainActivity.kt... However it causes a crash with this error now: Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 20468
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @MicheleRava the Activity is fully constructed only after calling setContentView inside onCreate. You cannot use findViewById prior to that

Comment: My DownloadManager custom class execute later... in theory. It seems that, instead, when i activate the download the Activity has not been fully constructed... how can I do to make it right?

Comment: @MicheleRava maybe post more code, because I can't guess.

Comment: I updated the question... however now it doesn't crash ( i solved an error I didn't see before...) and the progressBar doesn't get any update :/ Thanks for help, I think I must study a bit more my code

Comment: @MicheleRava Use LocalBroadcastReceiver to send your Download percentage to your activity or fragment and update progressbar there according to it.

Comment: Thank to all, I solved just sending the progressBar as a var into the Downloader Class. I will post it as soon as I can. I hope it's not a "wasting resources way", since I'm not sure yet about stopptig threads (Is it right that Kotlin does it by itself?)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it works the same way in Kotlin.

But there's a better way in Kotlin:

Add the following line to your apps build.gradle:
`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Now, you can access the View by its id:

e.g. `myProgressBar.progress = 30`

More: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to build.gradle: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions`

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MyActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Instead of findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.setText("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

This can be done outside of onCreate as well.

Comment: Yes, it works in all functions inside my MainActivity.kt... However it doesn't work in my "CustomClass.kt" file

Comment: does CustomClass extend Activity? does it say **class CustomClass : Activity()**? It **must** extend Activity for that to work.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. I created a custom class to handle the DownloadManager. Inside it I created a thread to keep track of the download % and now my goal is to send those values to my progressBar

Comment: I just added a contructor with :Activity() (as you suggested) and now it works

Comment: Ok, it seems my app crashes now... I think there must be maybe different problems inside
Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: the error is this: Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 20468
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference